# Proof Attempt: Soundness and Completeness of a Copi-style proof calculus for classical propositional logic.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

**Is the proof system given below, with 10 rules of replacement, 2 inference rules, and an axiom, sound and complete for classical propositional logic? Is the proof below of its soundness and completeness valid? Is there a faster way to prove that this system is sound and complete?**

It took me a couple of tries to produce this attempted proof of the completeness of this system, even though soundness was straightforward. I'm also not entirely pleased with the truth table proof calculus construct, although, at least for me, it was easier to conceptualize translating from one proof system to another than to prove that every true statement has a proof. The truth table idea is inspired by [this paper by Jean-Yves Béziau](https://www.jyb-logic.org/papers/morgan.pdf), although I only partially understand that paper and I'm just using truth tables in a fairly trivial way as scaffolding. I also tried to minimize the use of proof by contradiction or proof by contrapositive.

I suspect there's a much faster way to prove that this proof system is sound and complete using the class of Boolean algebras as a semantics for classical logic and the soundness and completeness of [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic), but I wasn't sure how to construct that argument.

---

##### List of errors found so far:

1. In the proof of theorem 130, I assumed that I can go from a $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$ to $\Gamma'' \vdash_T \varphi$ for a finite $\Gamma''$ by throwing out formulas that contain a free variable not found in the conclusion. This is not true. Consider $\lnot A \lor B, \lnot B \lor C \vdash \lnot A \lor C$. Replaced with an invocation of the compactness theorem.

---

I saw a proof calculus for classical propositional logic using 19 rules [as described here](https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2012/rulesLogic.html).

This system is quite interesting. It is sound and complete except for the fact that it cannot validate any inferences of the form $\varnothing \vdash \varphi$ because it has no axioms.

Some of the rules like the rule of absorption $p \to q \vdash p \to p \land q$ (which could just as well be a rule of replacement as [pointed out in a question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323450)) are counterintuitive.

I tried using the connectives from [algebraic normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) $(+, *, 0, 1)$ and seeing whether I could get a simpler system. Let's call this signature $A$.

Let's take the following as rules of replacement:

$$ a + 0 = a \\ a + a = 0 \\ a + b = b + a \\ a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c \\ a0 = 0 \\ a1 = a \\ aa = a \\ ab = ba \\ (ab)*c = a*(bc)  \\ (a+b)*c = ac + bc $$

And the following two rules of inference:

$$ \frac{ab}{a} \;\; \text{and}\;\; \frac{a \;\text{and}\; b}{ab} \;\; \text{are rules of inference} $$

I also have a single axiom, truth $\frac{}{1}$.

Let the system above be $\vdash$.

A proof in $\vdash$ is a nonempty directed acyclic multigraph $\pi = (V, E)$ where each $V$ is a finite set of well-formed $A$-formulas. Edges have no content, but each edge is constrained to have exactly one destination and exactly 0, 1, or 2 sources, depending on the number of premises for that inference rule. A proof is constrained to have finitely many edges and constrained to have finitely many non-isolated vertices (an isolated vertex corresponds to an unused hypothesis). Additionally, there must exist a single node, called the *conclusion* such that, for every non-isolated vertex $v$, there exists a path to the conclusion.

Let $\Gamma \models \varphi$ be the consequence relation for classical propositional logic. It is defined as follows:

$\Gamma \models \varphi$ if and only if for all valuations $v$ such that $v \models \Gamma$ it holds that $v \models \varphi$. $v \models \varphi$ for a well-formed formula $\varphi$ is defined using truth conditions as usual.

Let $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$ be the truth table proof calculus. A truth table proof is a table with all subformulas of $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ present and one row for each valuation mapping the variables to $\{0, 1\}$. If $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ are both variable free, a placeholder variable $x$ is used. Additionally, rows in the truth table may be **crossed out**. A row is crossed out if and only if at least one hypothesis in $\Gamma$ is false at that row. A proof of $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$ satisfies the additional constraint that $\varphi$ is true at every row that is not crossed out. If every row is crossed out, the table is still a proof. This is the reason for the placeholder variable restriction, without it, an empty table would prove $1 \vdash_T 0$.

Let $\alpha \lor \beta$ be an orthographic abbreviation for $\alpha + \beta + (\alpha * \beta)$.

Let $\alpha \land \beta$ be an alternative form of $\alpha * \beta$.

##### Proof sketch

I intend to show:

$$\vdash \;\;\text{implies}\;\; \models \;\; \text{implies} \;\; \vdash_T \;\;\text{implies}\;\; \vdash$$

##### Theorem 110: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ implies $\Gamma \models \varphi$.

Let $v$ be a truth valuation and $\pi$ be a proof of $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Let $\sigma$ be the substitution associated with the truth valuation $v$.

Let $\sigma(\pi)$ be the proof obtained by replacing each variable symbol $x$ with $\sigma(x)$ inside $\pi$.

Consider $\sigma(\Gamma)$. If $\bigwedge \sigma(\Gamma)$ reduces to $0$ then $\Gamma(v) \vdash \varphi(v)$ vacuously.

Suppose $\sigma(\Gamma)$ reduces to $1$.

The rules of replacement preserve the value of $1$ or $0$, so within $\pi$ we cannot get a vertex containing both formulas that evaluate to $1$ and formulas that evaluate to $0$.

The inference rule $\frac{ab}{a}$ can only produce a conclusion of $0$ when $a$ or $b$ (and thus $ab$) is $0$.

The inference rule $\frac{a \;\text{and}\; b}{ab}$ can only produce a conclusion of $0$ when $a$ is $0$ or $b$ is $0$.

Since none of the elements of $\sigma(\Gamma)$ are $0$, that means that $\varphi$ does not reduce to $0$ either.

Thus $\Gamma(v) \models \varphi(v)$.

Since we made no assumptions about $v$ other than that it's a valuation, this conclusion holds for all $v$.

Thus $\Gamma \models \varphi$.

End of proof of Theorem 110.

##### Theorem 120: $\Gamma \models \varphi$ implies $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$.

If $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ are variable free, let the relevant set of valuations be pair of valuations $\{\{x=0\}, \{x=1\}\}$.

Suppose $\Gamma \models \varphi$.

By definition of $\models$, for every valuation $v$, that $v \not\models \Gamma$ or $v \models \varphi$.

Let $V$ be the set of valuations. Construct a truth table proof by considering each valuation in turn and then evaluating all the subformulas of $\Gamma \cup \varphi$. If any of the top-level formulas of $\Gamma$ are false, cross out the row in question.

Suppose a valuation resulted in $\varphi$ evaluating to $0$. By the contrapositive of our hypothesis, at least one conclusion would be false and that row would be crossed out.

Therefore, every row that is not crossed out evaluates $\varphi$ to $1$, producing a valid proof.

As a further remark, note for contrapositive that $1 \vdash_T 0$ does not hold because the set of valuations always includes at least two valuations, and a candidate proof for $1 \implies 0$ would have no rows crossed out and $0$ associated with the conclusion in every row. Thus it wouldn't be a proof.

End of proof of Theorem 120.

##### Lemma 125: for finite $\Gamma$, $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$ implies $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Suppose $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$. Then there exists a truth table proof $\tau$ of $\varphi$ given $\Gamma$ and $\tau$ has finitely many rows.

If $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ are variable free, then $\tau$ will have two nearly identical rows, one of which assigns $x = 0$ and the other assigns $x = 1$.

For each row $r$, consider the formula $(a_1 \cdots a_n)((1+b_1)\cdots(1+b_m))$ where $a_1; a_n$ are the variables that hold at $r$ and $b_1; b_n$ are the variables that fail at $r$. Call this the *row formula*.

For any finite set of formulas $\Delta$, let $D(\Delta)$ denote the set of formulas $\{r_1, r_2, \cdots r_i\}$ where $r_i$ is the row formula for each row $r_i$. Let $E(\Delta)$ denote $r_1 \lor (r_2 \lor (r_3 \cdots r_n\;))$.

We have an equational proof from $E(\varphi)$ to $\varphi$, which can be constructed by converting both sides to arithmetic normal form, and then performing finitely many rearrangements of terms and rearrangements within terms to get the two sides to match syntactically.

We additionally have a proof from $\Gamma$ to $\bigwedge \Gamma$ and an equational proof from $\bigwedge \Gamma$ to $E(\Gamma)$.

Thus, we only need to show the existence of a proof from $E(\Gamma)$ to $E(\varphi)$.

By hypothesis, note that $D(\Gamma) \subset D(\varphi)$ and there are finitely many total rows. Therefore we can get from $E(\Gamma)$ to $E(\varphi)$ by finitely many application of a $\lor$-introduction rule if we had one.

Therefore, it suffices to show that $\frac{a}{a \lor b}$ is a conditional theorem.

$$ a \\ a1 \\ a(1+0) \\ a(1+b+b) \\ a + ab + ab \\ aa + ab + aab \\ a(a + b + ab) \\ \text{and thus by conjunction elimination} \\ a + b + ab \\ a \lor b $$

Putting this all together we can show in the proof system $\vdash$ that

$$ \Gamma \;\text{thus}\; \bigwedge \Gamma \;\text{thus}\; E(\Gamma) \;\text{thus}\; E(\varphi) \;\text{thus}\; \varphi $$

End of proof of Lemma 125.

##### Lemma 126: The identity rule $\frac{a}{a}$ is a conditional theorem.

We can prove this by introducing and then discarding a factor of $1$.

$$ a \\ a1 \\ \text{thus by conjunction elimination} \\ a $$

End of proof of 126.

##### Theorem 130: $\Gamma \vdash_T \varphi$ implies $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Suppose $\Gamma$ is infinite.

By the compactness theorem for classical propositional logic, if $\Gamma \models \varphi$, then there exists a finite $\Gamma''$ such that $\Gamma'' \models \varphi$.

Thus we now have two collections of proofs $\Gamma \vdash_T \gamma''$ for each $\gamma''$ in $\Gamma''$ and $\Gamma'' \vdash_T \varphi$. Note that we may need to insert a placeholder variable $x$ if $\Gamma$ and $\gamma''$ are variable-free.

Each of the proofs of the form $\Gamma \vdash_T \gamma''$ has a corresponding proof in the $\vdash$ system by virtue of the fact that $\gamma'' \in \Gamma$ and therefore only the identity rule needs to be applied. The identity rule is a conditional theorem by Lemma 126.

By Lemma 125, $\Gamma'' \vdash \varphi$ has a proof as well.

Thus, by composing the proofs, $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

End of proof of Theorem 130.

##### Theorem 140: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ if and only if $\Gamma \models \varphi$.

This follows by application of Theorems 110, 120, and 130 in the way outlined in the proof sketch.

End of proof of Theorem 140.

Comment: I haven't looked at your proof in detail, but under the standard semantics $a + a = 0$ is not a sound boolean principle ... but I assume your system is not a standard system since you don't have any negations! I'll see if I have some time later to take a look at what you are doing here ...

Comment: @Bram28, Thanks. I'm using a different set of connectives than usual $\{1, 0, +, *\}$ not $\{\land, \lor, \lnot\}$. $+$ is xor. I'm pretty sure that $a + a = (a \land \lnot a) \lor (\lnot a \land a) = 0 \lor 0 = 0$ holds. Negation is $x \mapsto 1 + x$.